# Repeated input by holding down key in Emacs

Tags: emacs, key, sequence, repeat

How to lower/remove the delay, and speed up the insertion of additional keys on holding down a key?

For instance: if you want to type a long `"ffffffffffffff"` sequence, when you do not care how many f's exactly, it takes quite some time when holding down the `f` to get the result.

There is a quite long initial delay, and the speed of the f's appearing after the delay is not the fastest either. Does anyone know which parameters are involved, and how to alter them?

Comment: Is this not a function of the operating system / keyboard driver? My highly scientific testing gives similair results in emacs and gnome-terminal and xterm

Comment: try pressing C-u 64 f (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/?action=browse;oldid=UniversalArgument;id=PrefixArgument). And yes, that's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: @MrBones this is correct, I fixed it through windows. Case closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Key repeat settings are always controlled by the base operating system, which you didn't state.  In the control panel or settings configuration for windows, osx, Linux, (and pretty much everything these days) there are two settings controlling key repeating.  The first is how long the delay is until the repeating starts, and the second is how fast the repeating occurs.

On unix systems (ie, X-window based), there is also the `xset` command line tool which can be used to change the keyrepeat:

```
# xset -h
... help output ...
To turn auto-repeat off or on:
    -r [keycode]        r off
     r [keycode]        r on
     r rate [delay [rate]]
```

And, as someone said, in emacs it's actually faster to insert a bunch of random characters by simply using `ctrl-u` followed by your random number and then hitting the key.  Or, in fact, you can use `alt-6 alt-4 f` as well.

(yes it's technically `meta` in emacs, but your key is likely labeled `alt`)

Comment: Unless your X server is cygwin based, in which case this doesn't work but restarting the X server will make it pick up the windows settings.